# Wrong (?) datatype generated with soaplib

Tags: python, wsdl, soaplib

I'm having a problem with soaplib.
I've the following function provided by a web service :

```
@soap(Integer, Integer, _returns=Integer)
def test(self, n1, n2):
    return n1 + n2
```

The corresponding declaration for the datatypes in the generated WSDL file is

```
<xs:complexType name="test">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="n1" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
    <xs:element name="n2" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>   
  </xs:sequence> 
</xs:complexType> 
<xs:complexType> name="testResponse">   
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="testResult" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>     
  </xs:sequence> 
</xs:complexType>
```

When I use some IDE (Visual Studio, PowerBuilder) to generate code from that WSDL file, whatever the IDE, it generates two classes for test and for testResponse, whose attributes are **Strings**.

Does anyone know if I can tweak my Python declaration so that I avoid complexType and obtain real **Integer datatype** on my client side?

Comment: Well, the point is that my targeted client plateform doesn't understand the "integer" datatype keyword in the WSDL. On the other end, SoapLib doesn't have an "int" primitive. Both are valid, according to the [XSD schema](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/rnc/xsd.html)

Comment: Please accept your answer (when you can) instead of adding "solved" to the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fought with the same thing, but couldn't move away from soaplib.

So, I monkeypatch it this way:

```
from soaplib.serializers.primitive import Integer

class BetterInteger(Integer):
   __type_name__ = "int"

Integer = BetterInteger
```

And then move on with life.

However, the XSD spec defines both 'integer': "Represents a signed integer. Values may begin with an optional "+" or "-" sign. Derived from the decimal datatype."  and 'int' "Represents a 32-bit signed integer in the range [-2,147,483,648, 2,147,483,647]. Derived from the long datatype."

So, the better solution is:

```
from soaplib.serializers.primitive import Integer

class Int32(Integer):
   __type_name__ = "int"
```

And use your new 'Int32' class to type your input parameters.

[soaplib 1.0.0]

Answer (score 2):

I checked your code but i get same output. I am using [suds](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/) to parse the values.

```
In [3]: from suds import client

In [4]: cl = client.Client('http://localhost:8080/?wsdl')

In [5]: cl.service.test(10,2)
Out[5]: 12
```

But when i check the type of that value.

```
In [6]: type(cl.service.test(10,2))
Out[6]: <class 'suds.sax.text.Text'>
```

So SOAPLIB will be return string but from type of that data you can convert it.

I check the response by writing this

```
@soap(_returns=Integer)
    def test(self):
        return 12
```

So i get in SOA Client Plugin of Firefox response as

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<senv:Envelope 
      xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/03/addressing" 
      xmlns:plink="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/05/partner-link/" 
      xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include"                
      xmlns:senc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
      xmlns:s12env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/"  
      xmlns:s12enc="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding/"  
      xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"    
      xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
      xmlns:senv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"  
      xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"> 

      <senv:Body>
           <tns:testResponse>
               <tns:testResult>
                   12
               </tns:testResult>
           </tns:testResponse>
     </senv:Body>
</senv:Envelope>
```

From XML you cant get raw integer data.

Answer (score 1):

OK, not all datatypes of XSD are defined in soaplib. 
Integer is defined in soaplib and is seen in the WSDL file as an integer, which the .NET framework (used by PowerBuilder) failed to understand.
Int is OK for .NET/PowerBuilder but soaplib isn't defined in soaplib.

Thus, I moved from soaplib to **rpclib**. Those libs are very close (one is a fork of the other).